# RecyclerView behind cardView is clickable when it should not be

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a cardview, behind which there is a recyclerview of "Suggested Contacts", much like the default dialer in android. The CardView is placed to the bottom of the screen, and occupies about 70% of the screen, while the RecyclerView extends its height to match_parent. When the RecyclerView is scrolled, the CardView disappears and reveals the whole list.

The user can click on one of the RecyclerView's items to make a call directly. The issue is that items behind the CardView, which are not visible to the user, are also clickable.

How can I have the RecyclerView items which are visible only as clickable? (i.e. while the cardView is visible)

xml code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_suggested_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="expandSuggestions">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_suggested_contacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dialer_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

[...]
```

Comment: Do you set `onClickListener()` on your `CardView`? If not, you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your requirement is that the cardview should block all clicks, so that items below don't take the click right.

If that is the case and you are sure cardview is on top of the recyclerview you simply need to set an `onClickListener` on your cardview and do nothing inside it. Basically an empty click.

Or you can in xml for cardview add

```
android:onClick="nullClick"
```

and in the activity create the empty function

```
public void nullClick(View view) {
}
```

whichever way you like.

Comment: Neat and tidy, I didn't think about this and it's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can hide (setVisibility(View.GONE) item behind recycler, or set them not clickable

Comment: I take it you meant the item behind the CardView. Even so, if I set the RecyclerView visibility to View.GONE, it will affect the whole list. If I set it for the items below the RecyclerView.. Well screens have different sizes. How can I check that the CardView overlaps on top of the RecyclerView?